# How do I set up Eclipse/EGit with GitHub?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I've never used Git before and would like to learn.

I have a private repository with GitHub.

I've installed the EGit plugin for Eclipse.

I have a workspace where I do my work, generally: `~/Documents/workspace`.

I am able to add my GitHub repository and download it, but in doing so it creates `~/MyRepository`.

When I create a project, do I need to point it to `~/MyRepository`?

Also, how come when I make an edit and I say push to upstream it says up to date?

Comment: If you have never used Git before, I recommend reading http://book.git-scm.com/ and/or http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make sure your refs for pushing are correct. This tutorial is pretty great, right from the documentation:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#GitHub_Tutorial

You can clone directly from GitHub, you choose where you clone that repository. And when you import that repository to Eclipse, you choose what refspec to push into upstream.

Click on the Git Repository workspace view, and make sure your remote refs are valid. Make sure you are pointing to the right local branch and pushing to the correct remote branch.

Comment: Frankly that tutorial goes into way too much depth for a beginner user.  I've been using git for years now, and don't understand half of the options it talks about.  I can follow it up to pushing my repository into an empty github one, but when it comes to fetching remote changes I'm basically lost.

Comment: This video tutorial helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1kXlahkwd4

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse, go to Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> Name: any name like egit; Location: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates -> Okay. Now Search for egit in Work with and select all the check boxes and press Next till finish.

File -> Import -> search Git and select "Projects from Git" -> Clone URI.
In the URI, paste the HTTPS URL of the repository (the one with .git extension).  -> Next ->It will show all the branches "Next" -> Local Destination "Next" -> "Import as a general project" -> Next till finish.

You can refer to this Youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptK9-CNms98

Answer (score 4):

Install Mylyn connector for GitHub [from this update site](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/), it provides great integration: you can directly import your repositories using Import > Projects from Git > GitHub. You can set the default repository folder in Preferences > Git.

Comment: Can you import a private repo? I can't find a way.

Comment: Has the Mylyn connector been discontinued? The download links for it do not point to a valid location.

Comment: For privat Repos: Window > Open Perspective > Git Repository Exploring and right click > Paste Repository Path

Comment: The link in this answer is broken.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.