# IDE's sync with github

Tags: github, ide, geany

Are there any IDE's/text editors that can sync with github? Such as geany/action/light table etc. I've just started out learning python in my free time, using either my RPi or MacBook and would be nice to be able to streamline my files/projects. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse should do the trick. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5723957) question for GitHub, and Google Eclipse php.